# What is the fastest/easiest way to increase a number in a string variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell variable

```
$var = "AB-0045"
```

I would like to increase the number in the string to become "AB-0046".
I can do:

```
$newNumber = [int]$var.Substring($var.length -4,4) + 1
```

Which will give me the desired number 46, but then I have to append that 46 as a string to a new string "AB-00".
Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: No, there is not. Strings are not numbers, numbers are not strings, and if you want to create a new string value, you'll have to create a new string  value :)

Comment: Personally, I'd just use regex replace for this: `[regex]::Replace($var,'\d+$',{([int]$args[0].Value+1).ToString('0000')})`.

Comment: Maybe you could use an object instead that has a number property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have the integer, you'll have to convert back to string formatted in the way you'd like and concatenate.

I'd recommend adding to "AB-" rather than "AB-00" in case your number goes over 100.

To pad leading zeros, you can use the [-f operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

e.g. `"{0:d4}" -f 45`

You'll still need to get the integer first (45 in the example) from your original string.

Comment: OK, thanks, but the problem is, when I get 0045 and convert it to int to increase it, it becomes 45 and looses the zeroes.

Comment: That's what the -f operator is for

Answer (score 1):

I tested with regex class `Replace()` method and string class `Split()` method with string formatter. `Split()` seems faster provided your string is always in the same format. The `Replace()` method does not care what happens before the last 4 numbers:

```
# Replace Method
[regex]::Replace($var,'\d{4}$',{([int]$args[0].Value+1).ToString('0000')})

# Split method
$a,[int]$b = $var.split('-'); "{0}-{1:0000}" -f $a,++$b
```